# Generate random number but not assigned UIButton

Tags: ios, random

I am trying to generate 7 random number each represent a `UIButton` using the code below.

But at the end, every time I generate using this code it gives the same buttons.

```
 NSMutableArray* rand_btns = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,nil];
        int randomTag = rand() % 20;
        int randomTag2 = rand() % 20;
        int randomTag3 = rand() % 20;
        int randomTag4 = rand() % 20;
        int randomTag5 = rand() % 20;
        int randomTag6 = rand() % 20;
        int randomTag7 = rand() % 20;

        [[rand_btns objectAtIndex:randomTag] setHidden:NO];
        NSLog(@"%d",randomTag);

        [[rand_btns objectAtIndex:randomTag2] setHidden:NO];
        NSLog(@"%d",randomTag2);
        [[rand_btns objectAtIndex:randomTag3] setHidden:NO];
        NSLog(@"%d",randomTag3);
        [[rand_btns objectAtIndex:randomTag4] setHidden:NO];
        NSLog(@"%d",randomTag4);
        [[rand_btns objectAtIndex:randomTag5] setHidden:NO];
        NSLog(@"%d",randomTag5);
        [[rand_btns objectAtIndex:randomTag6] setHidden:NO];
        NSLog(@"%d",randomTag6);
        [[rand_btns objectAtIndex:randomTag7] setHidden:NO];
        NSLog(@"%d",randomTag7);
```

Comment: Use arrays (or some other container), not variables numbered from 1 to 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`arc4random()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/arc4random.3.html) instead, however if you must use `rand()` then seed it before using it with:

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

(this only needs doing once per process invocation, so can be done in the app delegate).

Answer (score 2):

use arc4random() insteade of rand()

Answer (score 1):

You also can try it :)

```
int randomTag = (int)((rand()/(CGFloat)RAND_MAX)*20);
....
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    int randNum = arc4random() % (20 - 0) + 0;
```

Its return every time a random number between (0 - 20).
If you want a random number between (10 - 20) Just use this code

```
    int randNum = arc4random() % (20 - 10) + 10;
```